# Trend analysis with unequal intervals and unequal ns

Tags: r, time-series, regression

I have data forest of fire (number of species burned by forest fire) for last 15 years. However, data have unequal interval (some species have data of 5 years, while others have 10 years) and unequal number (number of observations are also unequal). I want to see overall trend of forest fire (by species, by location etc) Is it possible to calculate a trend analysis using such data? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could apply interpolation to regularize your data. The interpolation function can be linear, step-like, polynomial, etc.

Comment: Depending on exactly what your data look like, you might try to fit a multilevel model. They quite seamlessly handle most of these issues.

Comment: If you can perform weighted regression, you might weight by the number of observations *if* it true that the he greater the number of observations in a year the greater your confidence in that year's data.

Comment: Thanks @SergeiRodionov for your suggestion. I have data on  time (year, month, day), species name and number of forest fire event. I don't know if interpolation method and/or multilevel model is possible in data with no independent variables. I just found "Orthogonal polynomial coefficients and trend analysis for unequal intervals and unequal Ns: A microcomputer application" [link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/BF03200967). I did not find helpful materials about it. Any suggestion please.

Comment: Interpolation is simply the process of making an irregular time series into an evenly spaced series by filling the gaps. Extrapolation is the technique of adding samples at the beginning and end of the interval to extend to an interval of longer duration. Once you regularize the input series, you can apply many forecasting algorithms such as ARIMA or Holt Winters.